# question for using "if" with requirement of word+any integer

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

here's my thought

for some reason it must be in this kind of form

```
text=input("plz type:")
constant=30
if text == "!dollar "+**any integer**
    print(any integer*constant)
```

How to make it work properly

Is it possible to use "if" with this kind of requirement?

and also get the integer on further calculation

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a regex:

```
import re

text = input("plz type:")
constant = 30
match = re.match(r'!dollar(\d+)', text)
if match:
    print(int(match.group(1)) * constant)
```